# Is it possible to let the boundary of application windows go lower than the dock?

Tags: mac, dock

Right now If I let the dock sit on the bottom of my screen without auto hiding, I can't drag the bottom boundary of the application window to a position lower than the dock. Is it possible to let the application window take up all the space as if the dock is hidden (so that the application windows are sitting behind the dock, not above it)?
I'm on mac with 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, with Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: On what macOS and OS update are you?

Comment: @Thinkr It's 2.4 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, with Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: Okay thank you. Could you include it to your questions?

Comment: @Thinkr sure, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to let the boundary of application windows go lower than the Dock in the default settings of macOS. The Dock is designed to be a fixed element on the screen and application windows are not allowed to go below it. This is because the Dock is meant to be easily accessible and provide a quick way to launch apps and switch between them.

However, there are third-party tools and utilities that allow you to customise the behaviour of the Dock and application windows. For example, there are utilities that allow you to hide the Dock completely, or change the position of the Dock to the side or top of the screen. These utilities may also allow you to configure application windows to appear behind the dock instead of above it.

One such utility is called [cDock](https://www.macenhance.com/cdock.html), which allows you to customise the appearance and behaviour of the Dock on macOS. With cDock, you can change the position of the dock to the left, right, or top of the screen, or hide it completely. You can also customise the appearance of the Dock and configure application windows to appear behind it.

Just keep in mind that using third-party utilities to customise the behaviour of macOS can potentially cause issues.

I myself haven't tested cDock, so I can't really vouch for it, but its webpage states that it allows you to "customize every detail of your Dock".

Answer (score 1):

Built into macOS is the ability to relocate the dock to be vertical on the right hand part of the screen.
System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Position on screen  Right